# PHP $_POST from dynamically generated form

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post, multidimensional-array

I am creating a form based on a user selection of $node_number ... so the form looks like:

```
function createForm($node_number) {
            echo "<form id=\"form\" name=\"form\" action=\"molecule_display.php\" method=\"post\">";
           for ($n = 1; $n <= $node_number; $n++) {
                echo "<fieldset class=\"step\">
                            <input id=\"node_title" . $n . "\" name=\"node_title" . $n . "\" />
                            <input id=\"node_comment" . $n . "\" name=\"node_comment" . $n . "\" type=\"textarea\"  />
                     </fieldset>";
                            }
            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"node_number\" value=\"" . $node_number . "\">
                    <button id=\"submit_node\" type=\"submit\">Submit</button>"
            echo "</form>";
            }
```

Which will create $node_number of versions of that form element. My question is how to dynamically name the form elements to be able to manage them easier when I am processing them. The way I'm doing it right now, by adding the $n iterator to the name attribute is not ideal I think.

I understand that I can declare the name="" attribute as an array like name[]="" ... in terms of giving each sub-element of the larger form a unique name.

I'm guessing I want a multi-dimensional array of the individual form segment ... just not sure how to best handle those within a form and within the $_POST variable.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You know you could simply use a single quoted string to prevent you from escaping all that stuff right (since you are already concatenating to insert variable values)?

Comment: I have a tendency to figure out an answer about 5 minutes after I post a question to Stack Overflow. I figured I can just put the $n iterator inside the [] of the name attribute to provide a key which I can then work with in the processing ...

Comment: RepWhoringPeeHaa ... not exactly sure what you mean ... can you post a brief example? Thank you

Comment: Instead of escaping all those double quotes you could simply use a single quoted string like: `echo 'Yay! I can just add "double quotes" now without escaping...';`

Comment: Wirone, Both answers gave me insight, but yes, yours was the better way to go. I didn't know I could only accept one answer. Thank you! That was a big help

Comment: RepWhoring ... hadn't even thought of that, but yes, Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it this way:

```
function createForm($node_number) {
    echo '<form id="form" name="form" action="molecule_display.php" method="post">';
    for ($n = 1; $n <= $node_number; $n++) {
        echo '<fieldset class="step">
        <input id="node_title'.$n.'" name="nodes['.$n.'][node_title]" />
        <input id="node_comment'.$n.'" name="nodes['.$n.'][node_comment]" type="textarea"  />
        <button id="submit_node" type="submit">Submit</button></p>
        </fieldset>';
    }
    echo '</form>';
}
```

And then get `$_POST['nodes']` which will be multidimensional array, which you can iterate with `foreach`. You will get `$_POST['nodes'][1] = array('node_title'=>... , 'node_comment'=>...);` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the array like you were saying in your post you should be able to access them pretty easily.

```
function createForm($node_number) {
    echo "<form id=\"form\" name=\"form\" action=\"molecule_display.php\" method=\"post\">";
    for ($n = 1; $n <= $node_number; $n++) {
        echo "<fieldset class=\"step\">
                  <input id=\"node_title_" . $n . "\" name=\"node_title[" . $n . "]\" />
                  <input id=\"node_comment_" . $n . "\" name=\"node_comment[" . $n . "]\" type=\"textarea\"  />
                  <button name=\"submit_node[" . $n . "]\" type=\"submit\">Submit</button></p>
              </fieldset>";
     }
     echo "</form>";
}
```

I also changed the submit_node to a name and gave it an array value because an ID must be unique, which will cause errors if you are referencing it somewhere.

You could loop through the results like this:

```
foreach ($_POST['node_title'] as $key => $response) {
    $title = $response;
    $comment = (!empty($_POST['node_comment'][$key])) ? $_POST['node_comment'][$key] : "";
    // Save title / comment here.
}
```

Comment: You're wrong, because you only got `id`s unique (`id=\"node_title[" . $n . "]\"`), but inputs' names are not.

Comment: Yeah, I saw popup about your edition too late. However, you didn't group nodes, but nodes' types (node_title, node_comment) and it coerce referencing to other arrays by key. In my answer nodes are grouped in common array element which I think is better way.

Answer (score 0):

Since every form has its own submit button, nothing stops you from using  `name="node_title"` in all of them. If you now add `<input type="hidden" name="index" value="$n">` and read this first, your logic becomes very easy.

Comment: No, actually each form doesn't have its own submit, I'm iterating over the node_title and node_comment elements however many times and then only submitting once. But casting a multi-dimensional array right in the name attribute solves all my problems.